# Store Comments in DB

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am looking for a solution for storing comments in the database, but it is not difficult at all:

In one table wants to write comments from several modules on the website.

I am currently creating a table using code 'comments table':

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('module_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comments modules table:

```
    public function up()
{
    //
    Schema::create('comment_module',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title',190);
        $table->string('name',190)->unique();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

for now everything is okay, but i have problem with select all comments for each blog post,gallery, etc..

blog, gallery - name of modules.

code for **Map.php** model

```
    public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'module_id');
}
```

**CommentModule.php** model

```
 public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'module_id');
}
```

**Comment.php**

```
public function module(){
    return $this->belongsTo(CommentModule::class);
}
```

and now how to pass a 'mmodule_id' ?

normal use with any relationships for one table will be like that:

```
$map->comments->body . . etc.
```

but for that construction don`t work, yes of course i can use raw query and use join, right ?

Is any option to use a Eloquent?

Comment: are you trying to relation comments with more then one model?

Comment: yes, first is **comment_module** and second is parent of id module, for example parent id of blog post, but will be more modules like blog.

Comment: sorry, probably I am dumb, but is unclear to me what is your actual working code and what are you trying to achieve, to me they seems mixed.

Comment: for now i using raw query 
```
        $comments = DB::table('comments')
            ->join('users', 'comments.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where([
                'comments.parent_id' => $map->id,
                'comments.module_id' => $module->id
            ])
            ->select('users.name', 'users.avatar','comments.*')
            ->orderBy('comments.created_at', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```
It working fine, how you can see i use joins, but is any options to use Eloquent?
just example $map->comments->where('parent_id',$map->id)
where $map is example module

Answer (score 0):

IMHO for what I understood you want to attach comments to more than one Eloquent Model. There is a clean example in the laravel docs with [Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

As summary you have to add two fields on the `comments` table: `commentable_id`(integer) and `commentable_type` (string).

After that you declare the relation on the **Comment** model:

```
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

And you can use the comments() relation in **each** model you want to attach comments, i.e.:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }

class Map extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }
```

Now you can retrieve comments as usual:

```
$post->comments;
```

To attach a new comment to a parent:

```
$post->comments()->create([array of comment attributes]);
```